# Jekyll website on Github pages not rendered as expected

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I cloned a Jekyll Theme - [Solid](https://github.com/st4ple/solid-jekyll) for use in my personal project website. When running it using `jekyll serve` locally, I get this as the output:

[image: host using jekyll on localhost:4000]
[image: img 2]

However, when I hosted it using Github Pages, this is what I get as the output:

[image: global image 1]
[image: global image 2]

Basically, all the images are loading. Even the network monitor in the browser shows status 200 for all the files, including stylesheets and scripts. There is no `404 Not Found` error for any dependency file.

Also, as per the instructions from the theme [README.md](https://github.com/st4ple/solid-jekyll/blob/master/README.md), I also changed the `_config.yml` accordingly:

```
baseurl: "/solid-tesing" #important: start with / -> repository name
url: "https://sahilarora535.me"
```

I also tried publishing the website as the main user website in the repository `username.github.io` with appropriate changes in the `_config.yml`, however, this also gave the same output. What and where is the error?

**Additional Information** - The `jekyll serve` command runs the server successfully, with 3 warnings. On removing the code with warnings, no change in the resulting website is seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. The original code had a `css` file with `yaml` block and `liquid` tags in it. I don't understand why it was being correctly rendered locally, however, `yaml` is not supported in `css`. I changed the extension of the `css` file to `scss` and everything worked like a charm.

However, I still am not sure if `yaml` actually works in `css`. The source code had a lot of bad tweaks to include site color variables in `_config.yml` to stylesheet file.

Comment: if its having the frontmatter dashes, it's processed by jekyll, otherwise not. So that would be ok, as Jekyll would process the scss then. But liquid tags... thats pretty weird :-) Happy you got it working!

Comment: @Christian yes. I also think it should have worked, since it worked very well locally. Also, when I replaced the `liquid` tags in the `css` file with their actual values and removed all the `liquid` tags, and then add a `yaml` block at the start of the file, even then the `css` was not rendered by Github, whereas it was still working for me locally. :|

Comment: Sahil, let me assure you this is usually not the experience one has with Jekyll. I think you got a weeeeeeird template. You should reconsider using it, b/c template updates... ugh.

Comment: @Christian that is indeed a probable reason. I've had bad experiences with templates in the past. Anyways, do you have any possible explanation as to why the code works differently locally and on GH-pages.

Comment: Not really. I just know GH changed a few things for security reasons. In example, plugins don't work without being marked safe. Maybe it has something todo with that